# Elegant way to select upcoming birthdays

Tags: mysql

After searching a while, I found no "good" solution to get the upcoming birthdays from a MySQL database with just one single select statement. I found many different strategies in the web but none of them worked really fine especially at the change of the year.

Now I want to share my final solution:

```
SELECT mem_id, mem_dateBirth, MONTH(mem_dateBirth), DAY(mem_dateBirth)
FROM rs_mem
WHERE mem_dateBirth IS NOT NULL AND 
      mem_dateBirth > '1900-01-01'
ORDER BY (date_format(NOW(), '%m%d') >= date_format(mem_dateBirth, '%m%d')),
         date_format(mem_dateBirth, '%m%d');
```

The result will be a list with all the upcoming birthdays (also if the birthday is after the year change).

Comment: Can you explain what `upcoming birthdays` means in your context?

Comment: Hi Jens, in my context it means that i want to retreive the members (users) whose birthdays will be the next relative to NOW().

Comment: If you know what next is you can use bewteen to compare dates: `select * from rs_mem where mem_dateBirth between <start> and now() order by mem_dateBirth `

Comment: Thanks, but what would <start> be? I just want to have the next e.g. 20 birthdays starting from now. If you consider the year in the query, you'll get a problem because you cannot simply use a date comparison due to the fact that the birthday years are in the past.

Comment: OK now is clear what is `next` means. (In my understanding next can also means next 10 day or somes thing linke that. In your case you can alse use: `select * from rs_mem
 where birthday >=now order by mem_dateBirth limit 20`

Comment: No Jens, I cannot because the year of the birthday will never be in the future. I wouldn't have asked if it would be that simple ;-)

Comment: @can you provide some sample data with the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, here is another way to order your result using a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT M.mem_id
     , M.mem_dateBirth
     , MONTH(mem_dateBirth) AS month
     , DAY(mem_dateBirth) AS day
FROM rs_mem M
WHERE IFNULL(M.mem_dateBirth, '1900-01-01') > '1900-01-01'
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN DATE_FORMAT(M.mem_dateBirth, '%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m%d') THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END DESC, date_format(mem_dateBirth, '%m%d');
```

I also modified your `WHERE` clause in order to make it shorter (use of `IFNULL`).

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL : TOP 10 is first 10 record, you can remove it for all records.

```
SELECT TOP 10 mem_id, mem_dateBirth, MONTH(mem_dateBirth), DAY(mem_dateBirth)
FROM rs_mem
WHERE mem_dateBirth IS NOT NULL AND 
      mem_dateBirth > '1900-01-01' AND
      mem_dateBirth > DATE()
ORDER BY mem_dateBirth
```

MYSQL : limit 0,10 is first 10 record, you can remove it for all records.

```
SELECT mem_id, mem_dateBirth, MONTH(mem_dateBirth), DAY(mem_dateBirth)
    FROM rs_mem
    WHERE NOT isnull(mem_dateBirth) AND 
          mem_dateBirth > '1900-01-01' AND
          mem_dateBirth > CURDATE()
    ORDER BY mem_dateBirth limit 0,10
```

Comment: Hi Abides, thanks for your comment - unfortunately you'll get no results because 'mem_dateBirth > CURDATE()' is looking for a birthday in future.